# UIButton and UILabel not showing up on device screen

Tags: xcode, uiview, interface-builder, iboutlet

I have a `UILabel` and `UIButton` in my Xib interface builder.  The 600x600 screen says what I'll dragging+dropping on is a View.

When I drag and drop the label and button onto the view, and make them `IBOutlet` properties, they seem to not be part of any view hierarchy.

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
```

They each have their own respective constraints.

Here's two images.

[Interface Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzSM6.png)
[Interface Builder Outlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYz1k.png)

I have synthesized both properties.  Do I need to do anything programmatically?  I thought Interface builder took care of everything, which is why I ask.  The class in question is a custom subclass of a `UIViewController`, so do I need to drag and drop on to a view controller instead?

Comment: First print the frames of UIButton and UILabel. Once you get the values you are able to make chnages in it.

Comment: I ended up getting {{0,0},{0,0}} for the NSLog print.

Comment: Now you have two approach: first: set these objects via coding and another one is try to understand autolayout concepts and manage the view.